# Do not save data from editing ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have table which dynamically add data. When I edit data in first table it is not saved in the first or the second table but should be.

```
    $scope.correctiveData = [
    [
      {"name":"Description of Corrective Action (1)","values":[]},
      {"name":"Action Taken By (name) (1)","values":[]},
      {"name":"Company (1)","values":[]},
      {"name":"Date (1)","values":[]}
    ]
  ];
/*---------------First table-----------*/
    <tr ng-repeat="col in correctiveData">
                <td><textarea>{{col[0].values[0]}}</textarea></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="{{col[1].values[0]}}"></td>
                <td><select ng-model="col[2].values[0]">
                        <option ng-repeat="com in company">{{com.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-append" id="date" class="datetimepicker" time ng-model="col[3].values[0]">
                        <input class="span2" class="inputIcon" type="text" data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm PP" ng-model="col[3].values[0]" required pattern="\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d\s(AM|PM)">
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
/*--------------------Second table-------------------*/
    <tr ng-repeat-start="data in correctiveData">
                <td>{{data[0].name}}</td>
                <td>{{data[0].values[0] || 'required'}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{data[1].name}}</td>
                <td>{{data[1].values[0] || 'required'}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{data[2].name}}</td>
                <td>{{data[2].values[0] || 'required'}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end>
                <td>{{data[3].name}}</td>
                <td>{{data[3].values[0] || 'required'}}</td>
            </tr>
```

When I wrote data from javascript like below

"`{"name":"Description of Corrective Action (1)","values":['Some value']}`"

it's show in both of tables but when I edit it it doesnt save.
Also tables are in two different templates wich loads from two different files but have same controller.

Comment: Use ng-model, not value={{}}.

Comment: OMG, you are right, thank's so much)